# why "istream& object" requires reference & and ifstream doesn't?

Tags: c++, g++

I understand no copy or assign for IO objects, so that we have to have reference sign `&` for istream/ostream objects. But why `ifstream/ofstream` or `istringstream/ostringstream` doesn't require a `&` to initialize an object? .

```
istream& input=cin;
ifstream infile;
infile("in");
```

istream needs a & and ifstream doesn't need a & to declare the variable.

Comment: Do you mean the variable declaration? Can you post code to show exactly where you are talking about.

Comment: yes, variable declaration.  "istream& input=cin;" while "ifstream infile; infile("in");" why one needs "&"? the other declaration doesn't?

Comment: Really not sure what the question is here.

Comment: What is your third statement supposed to do? `infile("in");` ? As far as I know, that doesn't compile (`ifstream` has no `operator()`)

Comment: sorry, should be infile.open("in"); I forgot @Pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two aren't *really* comparable; one has an initializer and the other doesn't.

But `std::istream input = cin` doesn't work because streams are not copyable. If you tried to initialize `infile` with an existing `ifstream`, you'd get the same error. Obviously, a reference entails no copying and so it works, aliasing the existing value.

Going the opposite way, if you leave out the initializer, then you *can't* have a reference because a reference requires an initializer. Instead, your stream will just default construct.